# Python shared file access between threads

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I have a thread writing to a file(writeThread) periodically and another(readThread) that reads from the file asynchronously. Can readThread access the file using a different handle and not mess anything up?

If not, does python have a shared lock that can be used by writeThread but does not block readThread ? I wouldn't prefer a simple non-shared lock because file access takes order of a millisecond and the writeThread write period is of the same order(the period depends on some external parameters). Thus, a situation may arise where even though writeThread may release the lock, it will re-acquire it immediately and thus cause starvation.

A solution which I can think of is to maintain multiple copies of the file, one for reading and another for writing and avoid the whole situation all-together. However, the file sizes involved may become huge, thus making this method not preferable.

Are there any other alternatives or is this a bad design ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can open the file multiple times and get independent access to it. Each file object will have its own buffers and position so for instance a seek on one will not mess up the other. It works pretty much like multiple program access and you have to be careful when reading / writing the same area of the file. For instance, a write that appends to the end of the file won't be seen by the reader until the write object flushes. Rewrites of existing data won't be seen by the reader until both the reader and writer flush. Writes won't be atomic, so if you are writing records the reader may see partial records. async Select or poll events on the reader may be funky... not sure about that one.

An alternative is mmap but I haven't used it enough to know the gotchas.